# QGLWidget's background won't change in either initializeGL() or paintGL()

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl

So I have this program should uses a QGLWidget, I'm still relatively new to using OpenGL and QT so I started following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18). However the background of my QGLWidget won't change no matter what I do (I'm using ubuntu not windows). Do I need to create a class for it inside the mainWindow.cpp or is what I've done enough for it to work?

This is what is shown when the program is executed. The QGLWidget on the right is completely black when it show be yellow with a red triangle 
[image: mainwindow]

Here is the promoted widget of the QGLWidget which is linked to the drawingArea class
[image: promoted widget]

Finally here's the code from the drawing area. It compiles fine and I cant see anything wrong with the logic hence my confusion.

#### drawingarea.h

```
#ifndef DRAWINGAREA_H
#define DRAWINGAREA_H

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWindow>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <GL/glu.h>
class drawingArea : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    drawingArea(QWidget *parent=0);

    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    virtual void paintGL();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    QOpenGLContext *context;
    QOpenGLFunctions *openGLFunctions;
};

#endif // DRAWINGAREA_H
```

#### drawingarea.cpp

```
#include "drawingarea.h"

drawingArea::drawingArea(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void drawingArea::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(1,1,0,1);
}

void drawingArea::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}

void drawingArea::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glColor3f(1,0,0);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0);
   glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,0);
   glVertex3f(0,0.5,0);
   glEnd();
}    

void drawingArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

}
```

Comment: when do you call the methods `drawingArea::paintGL()` and `drawingArea::initializeGL()` ? I think yoy should do so in the constructor of your class drawingArea

Comment: Assuming you're using Qt5 you should note that `QGLWidget` is obsolete.  Use `QOpenGLWidget` instead.

Comment: I didn't think that was necessary @Hayfa but I just tried it and i still have the same outcome

Comment: @G.M. I'm using 5.9.5 so I'll look into that thanks

Comment: @TavianT you are right, it is not necessary, i just checked an old project

Comment: @Hayfa any other ideas on whats wrong?

Comment: No, sadly. Have you tried using QOpenGLWidget  as @G.M. suggested ?

Comment: Using QOpenGLWidget worked with changing the background colour however the triangle doesn't draw to the screen!

Comment: @G.M. using QOpenGL fixed all the problems. you can write it as an answer if you want and I'll make it correct for anyone else suffering with this problem in the future

Comment: @Hayfa `drawingArea::paintGL()` and `drawingArea::initializeGL()` are virtual methods and called by Qts event handling